# Loop to create '$ scope' in javascript

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

How to make a loop to look like this:

```
$scope.items = [
{ id: 1 },
{ id: 2 },
{ id: 3 },
{ id: 4 },
{ id: 5 },
{ id: 6 },
{ id: 7 },
{ id: 8 },
{ id: 9 },
{ id: 10 } ];
```

I imagine it's something like this:

```
var keyName, value;   $scope.items =[
    for (i=0; i< localStorage.length; i++){
        keyName = localStorage.key(i);
        value = localStorage.getItem(keyName);
'{ id: value },'

    }
    ];
```

Please some help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var key, value;
$scope.items = [];

for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
    key = localStorage.key(i);
    value = +localStorage[key];
    $scope.items[i] = {id: value};
}
```

The purpose of the `+` before `localStorage` is to force the type (i.e. having `{id: 42}` instead of `{id: "42"}`), use parseInt() if you're not sure that the value is a number.

Comment: Thank you very far. 
the script you gave me back: 
null null null 0
and when I did: 
$scope.items[i] = {id: ''+value+''};
returned: 
NaN NaN NaN 0
what will?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for, can you explain further ?

Comment: in short, I'm sure that I should return strings.

Comment: Ok, I saw your edit. This script assume that the values in `localStorage` are valid (e.g. not `null` or not a string which isn't a number). You may add a `if` to verify if the value is correct before trying to using it. It also assume that `$scope`is defined and is an object.

Comment: Return from which function?

Comment: based on your script I did it and it worked. 
`var key, value;
$scope.items = [];

for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
    key = localStorage.key(i);
 value = localStorage.getItem(key)
    $scope.items[i] = {id: value};
} ` 
  Biduleohm thanks and sorry my english improvised.

Comment: Ok, but in your question you've asked for `value` to be a number so I write this code accordingly. In future when you ask to have a string put the `"` like this `{ id: "1" }` instead of `{ id: 1 }` ;) No problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will create the object that you requested:

```
var keyName, value;   
$scope = { items: [] };

for (i=0; i< localStorage.length; i++){
    id = localStorage.key(i);
    value = localStorage.getItem(id);
    $scope.items.push({ id:value});
}
```

If you just want the contents of localStorage, why not just use JSON.stringify(localStorage)